# Model output folder in sagemaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to run a training job using sagemaker sdk.
I set the `base_job_name` as `base-job-name` and model_dir as `s3://my-bucket/model-output/`,  The trained model, however, is at `s3://my-bucket/model-output/base-job-name-2020-10-12-21-30-42-748/output`.
Can I do something to remove the date-time part from the `base-job-name` folder? It is perfectly fine to overwrite files as a result.
I couldn't seem to locate any property in the documentation which can help me set this.
This is how I am creating the estimator

```py
estimator = TensorFlow(
    base_job_name='base-job-name',
    entry_point='model.py',
    source_dir=source_dir,
    output_path='s3://my-bucket/model-output/',
    model_dir='s3://my-bucket/model-output/',
    instance_type='ml.m5.large',
    instance_count=1,
    role=my_role,
    framework_version='2.2.0',
    py_version='py37',
    subnets=subnets,
    security_group_ids=security_group_ids,
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_sess,
    tags=tags
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to remove the date and time stamp from the output name. The reason for this is because if you run the estimator code, and then call the `.fit()` function upon it more than 1 time, you will be overwriting the output model data, event data, etc.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a way though, where we can control this behavior? Like overwriting the output model data is not a concern, on the contrary, with the new model, I might have to manually delete the old model artifacts to reduce the storge.

Comment: If you are really serious about modifying this behavior, you could probably create a fork of the sagemaker python-sdk & then creating a sagemaker notebook instance that uses that fork. Though I doubt it is worth your time.

Comment: Yeah, was just curious if I am missing anything and if there is a faster easier way of achieving that

Comment: Sorry, I am pretty sure there isn't a way. Although, you could set the folder at which the data is saved and just change it every time you run a new training session. 

See EstimatorBase: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html

More specifically, the "output_path" argument can be used to accomplish this. It's not exactly what you are looking for, but given no other option it's a possible workaround.